# Migrating Stored Procedure from PostgreSQL to Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to migrate the Stored Procedure from PostgreSQL to Oracle, can someone suggest me a free tool for doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQLDeveloper is free.

But really, if you are moving code from postgresql to oracle, more than likely it's not a simple matter for exporting and importing; you will need to do some coding.